# Redirect function after successful PDO insert

Tags: php, redirect, pdo

To put it briefly, I'm looking for a way to do a redirect after a successful PDO insert. Here is what I have so far.

**Function for redirecting**

```
<?php
function redirect_to($new_location) {
      header("Location: " . $new_location);
      exit;
    }
?>
```

**PDO INSERT**

Please note, I've trimmed some code in my example below to make it easier to read.

```
try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO location_info (`department`, `participant`, `activity`, `location`, `rec_injuries`, `rec_injuries_timeframe`, `non_rec_injuries` )
        VALUES (:department, :participant, :activity, :location, :rec_injuries, :rec_injuries_timeframe, :non_rec_injuries, :non_rec_injuries_timeframe, '{$id}')";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

for($i = 0, $l = count($_POST["department_name"]); $i < $l; $i++) { 

    $loc_info = array(':department' => $_POST["department_name"][$i],
                        ':rec_injuries_timeframe' => $_POST["injury_time_frame"][$i],
                        ':non_rec_injuries' => $_POST["non_rec_injuries"][$i],
                        ':non_rec_injuries_timeframe' => $_POST["non_rec_injury_timeframe"][$i],
                        ':competitor' => $_POST["competitor"][$i],
                        ':cost_per_pair' => $_POST["cost_per_pair"][$i],
                        ':usage_rate' => $_POST["usage_rate"][$i],
                        ':leakage' => $_POST["leakage"][$i],
                        ':cost_of_productivity' => $_POST["cost_of_productivity"][$i],
                        ':non_rec_impact' => $_POST["non_rec_impact"][$i],
                        ':non_rec_sprain' => $_POST["non_rec_sprain"][$i],
                        ':non_rec_puncture' => $_POST["non_rec_puncture"][$i],
                        ':non_rec_dermatitis' => $_POST["non_rec_dermatitis"][$i],
                        ':non_rec_infection' => $_POST["non_rec_infection"][$i],
                        ':non_rec_burns' => $_POST["non_rec_burns"][$i],
                        ':non_rec_cuts' => $_POST["non_rec_cuts"][$i],
                        ':rec_impact' => $_POST["impact"][$i],
                        ':rec_sprain' => $_POST["sprain"][$i],
                        ':rec_puncture' => $_POST["puncture"][$i],
                        ':rec_dermatitis' => $_POST["dermatitis"][$i],
                        ':rec_infection' => $_POST["infection"][$i],
                        ':rec_burns' => $_POST["burns"][$i],
                        ':rec_cuts' => $_POST["cuts"][$i],
                        ':condition' => $_POST["condition"][$i] );

$stmt->execute($loc_info);
}
 if ($stmt->execute()) {
        redirect_to($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/testing/tim/results.php"); 

}
}
 catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        print "<b>error:</b> " . $error;
    }
```

You'll see that I have an if statement for the redirect with `if ($stmt->execute()) {
        redirect_to($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/testing/tim/results.php");`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't think `redirect_to` is a thing in PHP. You will want to do something like `header('Location:'.'new/path/file.php');`

Comment: You may want to clarify your question a bit....

Are you looking to redirect AFTER all statements have been executed?
Are you trying to build all the statements, then execute them in bulk, and redirect after ALL are successful?

Comment: is `$stmt->execute()` being called twice? perhaps the second time it is not running a query like you expect.. And what is in the block above the value assignment of `$loc_info`? there is a closing curly brace above the if statement so if we don't know what is above that, it is difficult for us to know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where am I going wrong?

When you are adding A LOT of useless code.

Here goes the FULL code you need (save for the trimmed array):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO location_info (`department`, `participant`, `activity`, `location`, `rec_injuries`, `rec_injuries_timeframe`, `non_rec_injuries` )
    VALUES (:department, :participant, :activity, :location, :rec_injuries, :rec_injuries_timeframe, :non_rec_injuries, :non_rec_injuries_timeframe, '{$id}')";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
for($i = 0, $l = count($_POST["department_name"]); $i < $l; $i++) { 
    $loc_info = array(
        ':department' => $_POST["department_name"][$i],
        ':condition' => $_POST["condition"][$i]
    );
    $stmt->execute($loc_info);
}
redirect_to("/testing/tim/results.php");
```

This is all.

This code will redirect if all executes will be executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of a structure issue here...

If you're wanting to execute an indeterminate number of queries, then redirect after all queries have been executed successfully, then you need to track all the statement executions and errors.

If you want to throw an error the first time you have one, and stop inserting, then you just check the return result of the execute function and throw an error if it fails:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO location_info (`department`, `participant`, `activity`, `location`, `rec_injuries`, `rec_injuries_timeframe`, `non_rec_injuries` )
    VALUES (:department, :participant, :activity, :location, :rec_injuries, :rec_injuries_timeframe, :non_rec_injuries, :non_rec_injuries_timeframe, '{$id}')";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$errors = array();

for($i = 0, $l = count($_POST["department_name"]); $i < $l; $i++) { 

    $loc_info = array(':department' => $_POST["department_name"][$i],
                    ':rec_injuries_timeframe' => $_POST["injury_time_frame"][$i],
                    ':non_rec_injuries' => $_POST["non_rec_injuries"][$i],
                    ':non_rec_injuries_timeframe' => $_POST["non_rec_injury_timeframe"][$i],
                    ':competitor' => $_POST["competitor"][$i],
                    ':cost_per_pair' => $_POST["cost_per_pair"][$i],
                    ':usage_rate' => $_POST["usage_rate"][$i],
                    ':leakage' => $_POST["leakage"][$i],
                    ':cost_of_productivity' => $_POST["cost_of_productivity"][$i],
                    ':non_rec_impact' => $_POST["non_rec_impact"][$i],
                    ':non_rec_sprain' => $_POST["non_rec_sprain"][$i],
                    ':non_rec_puncture' => $_POST["non_rec_puncture"][$i],
                    ':non_rec_dermatitis' => $_POST["non_rec_dermatitis"][$i],
                    ':non_rec_infection' => $_POST["non_rec_infection"][$i],
                    ':non_rec_burns' => $_POST["non_rec_burns"][$i],
                    ':non_rec_cuts' => $_POST["non_rec_cuts"][$i],
                    ':rec_impact' => $_POST["impact"][$i],
                    ':rec_sprain' => $_POST["sprain"][$i],
                    ':rec_puncture' => $_POST["puncture"][$i],
                    ':rec_dermatitis' => $_POST["dermatitis"][$i],
                    ':rec_infection' => $_POST["infection"][$i],
                    ':rec_burns' => $_POST["burns"][$i],
                    ':rec_cuts' => $_POST["cuts"][$i],
                    ':condition' => $_POST["condition"][$i] );

    if(!$stmt->execute($loc_info)){
        $errors[] = $e->getMessage();

        // un-comment if you want to stop on error:
        // print "<b>error:</b> " . $e->getMessage();
        // die();
    };
}

if(count($errors)){
    foreach($errors as $error){
        print "<b>error:</b> " . $e->getMessage()."<br/>";
    }
} else {
    redirect_to($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/testing/tim/results.php");
}
```

Comment: Your code is 1. Useless 2. Won't work anyway, That $e->getMessage(); thingy doesn't work the way you think. In fact PHP can do everything you said - track errors and check success without any extra line of code. Check the code I posted.

Comment: @YourCommonSense:
2) You're right, I should have used `$stmt->errorInfo()` instead of `$e->getMessage();`. "That $e->getMessage(); thingy doesn't work the way you think" actually does work the way I think... I just didn't mean to use it here.  

1) This code isn't useless, just maybe not appropriate for the way the OP's intended use.  

0) LPT: Don't be such a dick.